# jquery to fetch set of span element's value

Tags: jquery

My div appear as below:

```
 <div id="customfield_11504-val" class="value type-multiselect editable-field inactive"     data-fieldtype="multiselect" data-   fieldtypecompletekey="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multiselect"    title="Click to edit">
 <div class="shorten" id="customfield_11504-field" style="height: auto;">
   <span>option 3</span>
                         ,
       <span>option 2</span>
                            , 
        <span>option 1</span>
  </div>
 <span class="overlay-icon icon icon-edit-sml"/>
</div>
```

I have wrote below jQuery stuff:

```
var ret = AJS.$.trim(AJS.$('#customfield_11504-val .shorten span').map(function () {
    return AJS.$(this).html();
}).get().join(", "));
console.log("ret is:" + ret);
```

It prints me as below:

> [object HTMLSpanElement], [object HTMLSpanElement], [object HTMLSpanElement]

whats wrong here.. i tried, text but still just give me this only.

Comment: Seems working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqW89/)

Comment: thanks, i just pasted and it works fine. please add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var ret = $.trim($('#customfield_11504-val .shorten span').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
}).get().join(", "));

console.log("ret is:" + ret);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LqW89/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var spanValues = [];
$('.shorten span').each(function() {
    spanValues.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(spanValues);
```

Will serve your cause.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$(this).text() ;
```